# No digits in foldcolumn?

Tags: vimrc, folding, fold-marker

I would like my foldcolumn to have `foldcolumn=1` width and to show *only* `-`, `+`, and `|` (happy to have an indication of the existence of a deeply nested fold, I don't need to know what the actual level of it is)

Is there a way to do this?  I know I can customize `fillchars` but digits still appear in the foldcolumn even after explicitly setting `fillchars+=foldclose:+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible right now.
But nvim has an open PR, wich looks to me as if it is not that far away from getting merged.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/17446